# Unfortunately, “App Name” has stopped. (Eclipse, Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am somewhat new to Android app Programming.
I was able to create the app and be able to export it and install it to my android device, but when I try to run it it quits and displays the message "Unfortunately, My First App has stopped." This problem is also present when I try to run the app in an emulator

This is my AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tada"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my mainactivity file:

```
package com.example.tada;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    item.getItemId();
    return true;
 }
}
```

This is my activity_main file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tada.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/welcome_to_the_tada_app" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my LogCat

11-23 01:22:21.520: D/AndroidRuntime(1055): Shutting down VM
11-23 01:22:21.520: W/dalvikvm(1055): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3afbba8)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055): Process: com.example.tada, PID: 1055
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at com.example.tada.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-23 01:22:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 01:22:26.100: I/Process(1055): Sending signal. PID: 1055 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

When developing for android, always have a logcat window open.
When you see the crash dialog, the logcat will reveal the root cause of the error, making it easy for you to find it and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue of corrupted R.java file.....Immediately create a new project and do the code or switch ur sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `R.java` file and `Clean` your project. No need to create a new project.